# For Grid[], Frame of specific cells disappear with Dividers

Tags: grid-lines, frame

This (from the `Frame[]` help page) works fine:

> Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], 
>    Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {3, 3} -> True}}]

but this does not, as the frames disappear:

> Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], 
>    Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {3, 3} -> True}}, 
>    Dividers -> {{False, 6 -> True}, False}]

I have a workaround using `Item[foo,Frame->True]` but it is much uglier code.

Answer (score 5):

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], 
 Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {3, 3} -> True}}, 
 Dividers -> {6 -> True}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you! Should I have known this? I took the `Dividers` format also right out of the help page. Did my form somehow overwrite the `Frame`? Is this written up somewhere that I can read? Thank you again.  -- Aharon

Comment: @AharonNaiman you're welcome! Sorry, but I use not textbooks, but many years of programming experience. You can also experiment and see that `Frame` and `Dividers` are closely related in `Grid`.